Prove $\sum_{j=0}^{n} q^{j^{2}}\binom{n}{j}_{q^{2}}$ generates the self-conjugate partitions with part at most $n$.

Prove $\sum_{j=0}^{n} q^{j^{2}}\binom{n}{j}_{q^{2}}$ generates the self-conjugate partitions with part at most $n$, and that it equals $(1+q)(1+q^{3})\cdot\cdot\cdot(1+q^{2n-1})$.

For the first part, I considered looking at the Ferrer's diagram of a self-conjugate partition with largest part at most $n$. Such a partition $\gamma$ decomposes as a Durfee square of side $j$, a partition $\alpha$ of at most $j$ parts (each of size at most $n-j$), and a partition $\beta$ of at most $n-j$ parts, each of size at most $j$.
Now the Durfee square is generated by $q^{j^{2}}$, and $\alpha$ is generated by $\binom{n}{j}_{q}$. I am unsure how to proceed because of the $q^{2}$ in the $q$-binomial coefficient.
For part 2, I know that the number of such self-conjugate partitions is equal to the number of partitions into distinct odd parts and the result follows.
Any help is appreciated!

Importantly, since you’re counting self conjugate partitions, $\alpha$ must be equal to $\beta$. So, you make a single choice which contributes double the normal weight. You just need to see this is algebraically substituting $q^2$ for $q$ in the generating function for choosing $\alpha$.

@MikeEarnest Thanks, this is clear!

First, you need to show that every self-conjugate partition $\lambda$ corresponds uniquely to a number $j$ and a partition $\alpha$ with at most $j$ parts whose sizes are at most $n-j$, via
$$
\lambda=(\alpha+j^j)\cup \alpha'.
$$
Here $\alpha'$ is the conjugate of $\alpha$. Therefore, letting $\sum_{\lambda}$ refer to the sum over all self-conjugate partitions, and letting $Q(n-j,j)$ be the number of partitions with at most $j$ parts whose sizes are at most $n-j$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\lambda}q^{|\lambda|}
  &=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{\alpha\in Q(n-j,j)}q^{|(\alpha+j^j)\cup \alpha'|}
\\&=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{\alpha\in Q(n-j,j)}q^{|\alpha|+|j^j|+|\alpha'|}
\\&=\sum_{j=1}^n q^{j^2} \sum_{\alpha\in Q(n-j,j)}\big(q^{2}\big)^{|\alpha|}
\\&=\sum_{j=1}^n q^{j^2} \binom{n}j_{q^2}
\end{align}$$
In the last step, we are taking the equation $\sum_{\alpha\in Q(n-j,j)}x^{|\alpha|}=\binom{n}j_x$, and substituting $x\gets q^2$.
